# how to change Font size of one string "Hello" and display it in console?

Tags: java

I want to increase the font size of "Hello" except the other strings,
and to make it display in the console by [System.out.println].
How can I make it and see the bigger size "Hello" in the console of eclipse?
[java]

Comment: You can look at some console information here --> http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-consoleAppearance.htm

Answer (score 1):

The console (and, in general, strings in Java and other languages) deals with "[plain text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_text)". Plain text has no notion of text size or formatting. You cannot do that. You can only change (globally, from the outside) the settings of the console program - among those settings there should be the (global) text size.